# LaTeX2e 2019/10/01 update changes \lbrace vs \lcbrace test result

Tags: latex-base, mtpro

Prior to the LaTeX2e 2019/10/01 update, the following test with `mtpro2` gives

```
% Intended output:
True
False
True
```

Now it gives

```
% After LaTeX2e 2019/10/01 update:
False
False
False
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
% Default is curly braces, test result changed from True to False
\ifx\lbrace\lcbrace
  True%
\else
  False%
\fi

% Switch to straight braces, test result remains False
\straightbraces
\ifx\lbrace\lcbrace
  True%
\else
  False%
\fi

% Switch back to curly braces, test result changed from True to False
\curlybraces
\ifx\lbrace\lcbrace
  True%
\else
  False%
\fi
\end{document}
```

This seems to be caused by the new kernel “robustifying” `\lbrace` and all other math delimiters:

1. `mtpro2` first does `\let\lcbrace=\lbrace`. This makes `\lcbrace` pointing to the robustified version of `\lbrace`.
2. `mtpro2` then execute one of `\curlybraces`, `\straightbraces` and `\morphedbraces`. This does `\def\lbrace{\delimiter<whatever> }`, making `\lbrace` non-robust.

I would like to maintain the original test results. Ulrike Fischer’s solution in the comments seems an overkill: Because `mtpro2` has already made `\lbrace` non-robust, one can just issue `\def\lcbrace{\delimiter"4266308 }` rather than loading another package.

My questions are: Is there harm for undoing the robustifying? Or, is there a better test? (The goal is to determine the current brace shapes in math mode: Curly versus non-curly.)

Comment: The package does `\let\lcbrace=\lbrace` which fails now, as \lbrace is robust now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, see update. My current idea is to issue `\def\lcbrace{\delimiter<whatever> }` to undo the robustifying.

Comment: Redefine the command `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\lcbrace}{\lbrace}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But the `mtpro2` package also does `\curlybraces`, which expands to `\def\lbrace{\delimiter"4266308 }...`, *after* it does `\let\lcbrace=\lbrace` (as default)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new test which also works if running on old kernel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\ifx\csname lbrace \endcsname\relax
%   Before the ltfssdcl.dtx 2019/08/27 v3.0s update, \lcbrace
% pointed to a non-robust \lbrace (\delimiter"4266308 ). So a
% straightforward comparison test is possible.
\newcommand*\ifcurlybraces{%
  \ifx\lcbrace\lbrace
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\else
%   Since ltfssdcl.dtx 2019/08/27 v3.0s, the LaTeX2e kernel
% makes math delimiters robust (including \lbrace, \rbrace).
% But mtpro2 uses the non-robust definitions. So we need to
% use a different test.
\newcommand*\ifcurlybraces{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname lbrace \endcsname\lbrace
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\{\bigl\{\Bigl\{\biggl\{\Biggl\{$
\ifcurlybraces{True}{False}

\straightbraces
$\{\bigl\{\Bigl\{\biggl\{\Biggl\{$
\ifcurlybraces{True}{False}

\morphedbraces
$\{\bigl\{\Bigl\{\biggl\{\Biggl\{$
\ifcurlybraces{True}{False}

\curlybraces
$\{\bigl\{\Bigl\{\biggl\{\Biggl\{$
\ifcurlybraces{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

[image: new test]

Comment: using `\ifcsname lbrace \endcsname` is probably easier